# Why cant I export and use my custom js styles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This my main class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import styles from './FoodStyles';

class Food extends Component {
  render () {
    return (   
      <div>
        <h2 className="header">Food</h2> 
      </div>
    )        
  }   
}

export default withStyles(styles) (Food);
```

And this is my style class called FoodStyles.js

```
const styles = theme => ({  
  header: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
});

export default styles;
```

They both are in the same folder but still styles cannot be accessed

Comment: `Food` doesn't seem to use `styles` at all.

Comment: Its not enought to use it like this: export default withStyles(styles) (Food);

Comment: I would expect it to pass a prop to Food which it can then use.

Comment: Don't you mean: `<h2 className={styles.header}>`?

Comment: Double check with the documentation https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the solution to your problem: (You need destructuring as done in line 7 for your styles to be used in your file.) With React, which fully embraces the ES6 syntax, destructuring adds a slew of benefits to improving your code.

**Food.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import styles from './styles';

class Food extends Component {
  render () {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (   
      <div>
        <h2 className={classes.header}>Food</h2> 
      </div>
    )        
  }   
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Food);
```

**styles.js:**

```
const styles = theme => ({  
    header: {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
  });
  
  export default styles;
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Reasons to destructure:**

**1. Improves readability:**
This is a huge upside in React when you’re passing down props. Once you take the time to destructure your props, you can **get rid of props / this.props** in front of each prop.

**2. Shorter lines of code:**
Insead of:

```
var object = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
var one = object.one; 
var two = object.two; 
var three = object.three
console.log(one, two, three) // prints 1, 2, 3
```

We can write:

```
let object = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
let { one, two, three } = object;
console.log(one, two, three) // prints 1, 2, 3
```

**3. Syntactic sugar:**
It makes code look nicer, more succinct, and like someone who knows what they’re doing wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `makeStyles` instead of `withStyles`.

#### App.jsx

```
import Food from "./Food";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Food />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

#### Food.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import styles from "./FoodStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

const Food = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className={classes.header}>Food</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Food;
```

#### FoodStyles.js

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  header: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
});

export default styles;
```